Why do the supposed super resolution images from SRGAN appear in RGB colors?
I am using this srgan script to try to generate super resolution satellite images. A few things I modified are input images, shapes and saving images. Anyone understands why the images generated looks like: this.
Also, why are the rgb pixels each assigned a value of 1 and the other colors getting zero point something? The range of the input datasets is between 0 and 0.6 for all images.
loading low resolution images:
s2_image = []
def load_s2_images(s2):
    for file in os.listdir(s2):
        if file.endswith('.TIF'):
            file_path = os.path.join(s2, file)

            dataset = gdal.Open(file_path, gdalconst.GA_ReadOnly)
            red = dataset.GetRasterBand(4).ReadAsArray()
            green = dataset.GetRasterBand(3).ReadAsArray()
            blue = dataset.GetRasterBand(2).ReadAsArray()
            # coastal = dataset.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray()
            # nir = dataset.GetRasterBand(8).ReadAsArray()
            # redEg = dataset.GetRasterBand(5).ReadAsArray()

            s2_nparray = np.stack((red, green, blue), axis=-1)#, coastal, nir, redEg), axis=-1)

            s2_image.append(s2_nparray)
            
    return s2_image
            
s2_image_arrays = load_s2_images(s2)

saving images
def save_generated_images(epoch, generator_model, s2_test, output_dir):
    generated_sr_images = generator_model.predict(s2_test)
    for ni, image in enumerate(generated_sr_images):
        plt.imsave(f"{output_dir}/epoch_{epoch}_image_{i}.png", image)

I split all images into 32*32, and I was expecting that when I load them into arcgis, they are next to each other instead of overlaying on top of each other. If it helps, I tested both on the pretained imagenet model and the VGG from scratch.

I'm not sure exactly what you're objecting to.  Your stack operation takes three NxM arrays and produces an NxMx3 array, which will be interpreted as RGB.

Actually, I am expecting a super resolution image to technically look similar to or better than the low resolution image and not like it is at the moment.
